# React List of objects not rendering when using filter

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to render my tasks which are nested inside the project object and I have a list of project objects. What's the approach I need to use and what I am missing.

- What I am doing is iterate through each project and take tasks associated with it and filter out tasks assigned to **User1** and print them as Output.
- But I don't know my it was not rendering.

```js
const App= props => {

  const projects = [
    {
      "id": "1JEM8ivAlH073ngLtc3V",
      "team": "Engineering",
      "priority": "Highest",
      "tasks": [
        {
          "description": "Hello World",
          "status": "Open",
          "assigine": "User1",
          "priority": "Low",
          "name": "Friend"
        }
      ],
      "visibility": "Public",
      "name": "Radiance",
      "Owner": "DVcjkvnCuV59RpxxrSbnxHK9rAgfaVriXK3NX51eiv3i",
      "description": "ABCDEFGHIJ"
    },
    {
      "id": "dHMVewmo7HYfUSgqDwhH",
      "team": "Engineering",
      "tasks": [
        {
          "name": "Implement adapter ",
          "status": "Open",
          "description": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.\n\n",
          "priority": "Highest",
          "assigine": "User1"
        },
        {
          "description": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.\n\n",
          "priority": "Medium",
          "name": "Replace old text with new text",
          "status": "Doing",
          "assigine": "User2"
        },
        {
          "priority": "Highest",
          "description": "Loreum ipsum de djdasjknkajcnkjcnskax",
          "assigine": "User1",
          "name": "SOL Mail",
          "status": "Open"
        }
      ],
      "description": "ABCDEFGHIJ",
      "Owner": "DVcjkvnCuV59RpxxrSbnxHK9rAgfaVriXK3NX51eiv3i",
      "visibility": "Public",
      "name": "Friend",
      "priority": "Highest"
    },
    {
      "id": "2Ld5Afb5Q9TNtqsNRfmc",
      "priority": "Highest",
      "description": "The react-router-dom package contains bindings for using React Router in web applications. Please see the Getting Started guide for more information on how to get started with React Router.",
      "name": "Developers DAO",
      "tasks": [
        {
          "name": "Fix Deprecated libraries",
          "status": "Open",
          "assigine": "User1",
          "description": "Implement Dashboard ",
          "priority": "Highest"
        },
        {
          "description": "Fix Deprecated libraries",
          "name": "Dikiri Dikiri",
          "priority": "Highest",
          "assigine": "User2",
          "status": "Open",
          "visibility": "Doing"
        },
        {
          "status": "Open",
          "assigine": "User2",
          "description": "Change Authentication Mode",
          "priority": "Highest",
          "name": "SOL Mail"
        },
        {
          "priority": "Highest",
          "assigine": "User1",
          "status": "Open",
          "description": "Modification of User Interface",
          "name": "Hello World"
        },
        {
          "priority": "Medium",
          "name": "Hello Bussy",
          "description": "React routes modification",
          "assigine": "User3",
          "status": "Doing"
        },
        {
          "status": "Open",
          "assigine": "User2",
          "priority": "Highest",
          "name": "Friend",
          "description": "Hello World"
        }
      ],
      "visibility": "Private",
      "Owner": "DVcjkvnCuV59RpxxrSbnxHK9rAgfaVriXK3NX51eiv3i",
      "team": "Engineering"
    }
  ];

  return <div>
          <h1>Hello World</h1>
          {
            projects.forEach(function (project) {
                    const tasks = project.tasks.filter(task => task.assigine === "User1");
                    console.log("tasks was here ",tasks);
                    tasks.map((row) => {
                    console.log("row is here ",row);
                    return <div>
                            <p>{row.name}</p>
                            <p>{row.description}</p>
                    </div>
                  })
                })
          }
        </div>
}


ReactDOM.render(
    <App/>,
    document.body
  );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You're not doing anything with the array that `map` returns.

Comment: Side note: Your other property names are in English, so I'm guessing you meant `assigine` to be English as well. If so, it's spelled `assignee` (the person something is assigned to).

Comment: I just need to output each task name and description.

Comment: I don't need any search option or useEffect I have my projects loaded alredy.

Comment: Could you please use my snippet so that it will be more understandable. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Thanks for your patience let me figure it out myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The principal issues are:

- `forEach` always returns `undefined`.
- You're not using the array that map creates anywhere, so it just gets thrown away.

If you want a list of tasks, you'll need to extract it from the list of projects. The simple way to do that is to create a blank array and add matching tasks. Or you can map the array of projects to an array of matching tasks (which may be empty for a project with no matching tasks) and then flattening that array.

Here's the loop version:

```
const taskRows = [];
for (const { tasks } of projects) {
    for (const { name, description, assigine } of tasks) {
        if (assigine === "User1") {
            taskRows.push(<div>
                <p>{name}</p>
                <p>{description}</p>
            </div>);
        }
    }
}
return <div>
    <h1>Hello World</h1>
    {taskRows}
</div>;
```

Live Example:

```js
const App = props => {

    const projects = [
        {
            "id": "1JEM8ivAlH073ngLtc3V",
            "team": "Engineering",
            "priority": "Highest",
            "tasks": [
                {
                    "description": "Hello World",
                    "status": "Open",
                    "assigine": "User1",
                    "priority": "Low",
                    "name": "Friend"
                }
            ],
            "visibility": "Public",
            "name": "Radiance",
            "Owner": "DVcjkvnCuV59RpxxrSbnxHK9rAgfaVriXK3NX51eiv3i",
            "description": "ABCDEFGHIJ"
        },
        {
            "id": "dHMVewmo7HYfUSgqDwhH",
            "team": "Engineering",
            "tasks": [
                {
                    "name": "Implement adapter ",
                    "status": "Open",
                    "description": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.\n\n",
                    "priority": "Highest",
                    "assigine": "User1"
                },
                {
                    "description": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.\n\n",
                    "priority": "Medium",
                    "name": "Replace old text with new text",
                    "status": "Doing",
                    "assigine": "User2"
                },
                {
                    "priority": "Highest",
                    "description": "Loreum ipsum de djdasjknkajcnkjcnskax",
                    "assigine": "User1",
                    "name": "SOL Mail",
                    "status": "Open"
                }
            ],
            "description": "ABCDEFGHIJ",
            "Owner": "DVcjkvnCuV59RpxxrSbnxHK9rAgfaVriXK3NX51eiv3i",
            "visibility": "Public",
            "name": "Friend",
            "priority": "Highest"
        },
        {
            "id": "2Ld5Afb5Q9TNtqsNRfmc",
            "priority": "Highest",
            "description": "The react-router-dom package contains bindings for using React Router in web applications. Please see the Getting Started guide for more information on how to get started with React Router.",
            "name": "Developers DAO",
            "tasks": [
                {
                    "name": "Fix Deprecated libraries",
                    "status": "Open",
                    "assigine": "User1",
                    "description": "Implement Dashboard ",
                    "priority": "Highest"
                },
                {
                    "description": "Fix Deprecated libraries",
                    "name": "Dikiri Dikiri",
                    "priority": "Highest",
                    "assigine": "User2",
                    "status": "Open",
                    "visibility": "Doing"
                },
                {
                    "status": "Open",
                    "assigine": "User2",
                    "description": "Change Authentication Mode",
                    "priority": "Highest",
                    "name": "SOL Mail"
                },
                {
                    "priority": "Highest",
                    "assigine": "User1",
                    "status": "Open",
                    "description": "Modification of User Interface",
                    "name": "Hello World"
                },
                {
                    "priority": "Medium",
                    "name": "Hello Bussy",
                    "description": "React routes modification",
                    "assigine": "User3",
                    "status": "Doing"
                },
                {
                    "status": "Open",
                    "assigine": "User2",
                    "priority": "Highest",
                    "name": "Friend",
                    "description": "Hello World"
                }
            ],
            "visibility": "Private",
            "Owner": "DVcjkvnCuV59RpxxrSbnxHK9rAgfaVriXK3NX51eiv3i",
            "team": "Engineering"
        }
    ];

    const taskRows = [];
    for (const { tasks } of projects) {
        for (const { name, description, assigine } of tasks) {
            if (assigine === "User1") {
                taskRows.push(<div>
                    <p>{name}</p>
                    <p>{description}</p>
                </div>);
            }
        }
    }
    return <div>
        <h1>Hello World</h1>
        {taskRows}
    </div>;
};


ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
    document.body
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

But if you really want to use `map`:

```
const taskRows =
    projects.map(({tasks}) =>
        tasks.filter(({assigine}) => assigine === "User1")
    )
    .flat()
    .map(({name, description}) => <div>
        <p>{name}</p>
        <p>{description}</p>
    </div>);
return <div>
    <h1>Hello World</h1>
    {taskRows}
</div>;
```

Live Example:

```js
const App = props => {

    const projects = [
        {
            "id": "1JEM8ivAlH073ngLtc3V",
            "team": "Engineering",
            "priority": "Highest",
            "tasks": [
                {
                    "description": "Hello World",
                    "status": "Open",
                    "assigine": "User1",
                    "priority": "Low",
                    "name": "Friend"
                }
            ],
            "visibility": "Public",
            "name": "Radiance",
            "Owner": "DVcjkvnCuV59RpxxrSbnxHK9rAgfaVriXK3NX51eiv3i",
            "description": "ABCDEFGHIJ"
        },
        {
            "id": "dHMVewmo7HYfUSgqDwhH",
            "team": "Engineering",
            "tasks": [
                {
                    "name": "Implement adapter ",
                    "status": "Open",
                    "description": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.\n\n",
                    "priority": "Highest",
                    "assigine": "User1"
                },
                {
                    "description": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.\n\n",
                    "priority": "Medium",
                    "name": "Replace old text with new text",
                    "status": "Doing",
                    "assigine": "User2"
                },
                {
                    "priority": "Highest",
                    "description": "Loreum ipsum de djdasjknkajcnkjcnskax",
                    "assigine": "User1",
                    "name": "SOL Mail",
                    "status": "Open"
                }
            ],
            "description": "ABCDEFGHIJ",
            "Owner": "DVcjkvnCuV59RpxxrSbnxHK9rAgfaVriXK3NX51eiv3i",
            "visibility": "Public",
            "name": "Friend",
            "priority": "Highest"
        },
        {
            "id": "2Ld5Afb5Q9TNtqsNRfmc",
            "priority": "Highest",
            "description": "The react-router-dom package contains bindings for using React Router in web applications. Please see the Getting Started guide for more information on how to get started with React Router.",
            "name": "Developers DAO",
            "tasks": [
                {
                    "name": "Fix Deprecated libraries",
                    "status": "Open",
                    "assigine": "User1",
                    "description": "Implement Dashboard ",
                    "priority": "Highest"
                },
                {
                    "description": "Fix Deprecated libraries",
                    "name": "Dikiri Dikiri",
                    "priority": "Highest",
                    "assigine": "User2",
                    "status": "Open",
                    "visibility": "Doing"
                },
                {
                    "status": "Open",
                    "assigine": "User2",
                    "description": "Change Authentication Mode",
                    "priority": "Highest",
                    "name": "SOL Mail"
                },
                {
                    "priority": "Highest",
                    "assigine": "User1",
                    "status": "Open",
                    "description": "Modification of User Interface",
                    "name": "Hello World"
                },
                {
                    "priority": "Medium",
                    "name": "Hello Bussy",
                    "description": "React routes modification",
                    "assigine": "User3",
                    "status": "Doing"
                },
                {
                    "status": "Open",
                    "assigine": "User2",
                    "priority": "Highest",
                    "name": "Friend",
                    "description": "Hello World"
                }
            ],
            "visibility": "Private",
            "Owner": "DVcjkvnCuV59RpxxrSbnxHK9rAgfaVriXK3NX51eiv3i",
            "team": "Engineering"
        }
    ];

    const taskRows =
        projects.map(({tasks}) =>
            tasks.filter(({assigine}) => assigine === "User1")
        )
        .flat()
        .map(({name, description}) => <div>
            <p>{name}</p>
            <p>{description}</p>
        </div>);
    return <div>
        <h1>Hello World</h1>
        {taskRows}
    </div>;
};

ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
    document.body
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```